# Is warping solely caused by thermal stress on the printed material?

Tags: pla, temperature, warping, terminology

Is thermal stress the root cause of warping of printed parts? As in the (rapid) shrinkage of the cooling down material?

Either the material (PLA, ABS, PETG) is cooled down too fast either by too much cooling, too fast temperature changes of the bed, chamber or environment?

Comment: It's a terminology question and I don't think more details or clarity can be provided. Therefore, it should not be closed.